# What is the proper Facebook site URL for FB app?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to get a FB app approved for the app center and I keep getting the same message back:

on Web - Your web platform is a Facebook URL or redirects to a Facebook URL immediately after logging in. Revise your website URL, which is located in the app 'Settings' tab, under the 'Website' section. Learn more here.

I don't understand what needs to be in the Website platform as the site URL. Currently, I have this:

canvas page: https://apps.facebook.com/myapp (this page iframes blah.myapp.com which asks for FB login)

canvas URL: http://blah.myapp.com/

site URL: http://blah.myapp.com/ (which when you go to this page, you also are asked for FB login)

Any ideas what they want there?

Comment: That can not be your canvas URL – canvas URL is the URL where your app is located on _your_ server, that gets then loaded into the iframe when the user visits `https://apps.facebook.com/myapp`

Comment: @CBroe  - you are right, copied the wrong URL here. my canvas url is the same as the site URL. Will make an update to the post.

Comment: So what _does_ your website do after FB login? Do you keep the user on your website?

Comment: @CBroe - yes, there is a flash swf on the website, so after user logs in, they interact with the swf on that page. you can go through the steps here: https://apps.facebook.com/likemytank/

Comment: That’s your canvas app … the review response was about your website though. Do you actually _have_ a separate website version of your game? If not, then don’t specify Website platform for your app to begin with …

Comment: @CBroe - I c. the separate website version is just the iframe which is on the canvas app, but can be accessed outside of fb- http://game.likemytank.com

Comment: Well, that redirects to the FB login dialog with `…&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/likemytank/` at the end – so the user will end up on Facebook after login. Either make that point back to your own page – or don’t submit a _Website_ platform if you want it all to take place on facebook.com